# Are there any airworthy or transportable A-7 Corsair 2 aircraft as of October 2021?

Tags: military, airworthiness

I'm assisting in organizing an Aviation Open House, and we are searching for an A-7 Corsair 2.  The only examples we can find are static ground displays, none of which can be easily transported.  As of today, are there any air-worthy A-7 Corsair 2s in existence?

Comment: Have you tried searching the [FAA registry](https://registry.faa.gov/AircraftInquiry/Search/MakeModelInquiry) for Manufacturer Name = Vought and Model Name = A7 ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the internet searching I did it doesn't look very promising.

List of surviving A-7 Corsair IIs:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_surviving_LTV_A-7_Corsair_IIs

It looks like Greece flew the last ones, retiring the last one in October 2014. I have no way to see what they did with them after retirement.
https://theaviationist.com/2014/10/27/haf-retirement-a-7/

I don't know how current the info is at this site:
https://www.planelogger.com/Aircraft/ConstructionList/A-7

It lists ZERO A-7s in the Hellenic Air Force fleet (not even showing any as being stored):
https://www.planelogger.com/Airline/Fleet/Hellenic_Air_Force/172406

I just searched David Monthan AFB in Tuscon on Google Maps to see if there are any A-7s  because of this photo:  https://www.airliners.net/photo/USA-Navy/LTV-A-7E-Corsair-II/2446637
and do not see any A-7s stored outside there.

That's all I can figure out on the internet. Hopefully someone who has more specific knowledge will come along (I'm not a warbird expert by any means).

Answer (score 0):

I know there's a mostly functional one that can still fly in the Tulsa Tech Riverside campus in the state of Oklahoma, the campus is primarily for teaching students how to preform maintenance on an aircraft, and from what I remember, the instructors preform the maintenance on that aircraft, and occasionally start up it's engine. I'm not 100% sure it would be able to fly on a moments notice, but I'm pretty sure it would just need a minor bit of work and it would be good to go for flight from what the instructors have told me.

Comment: Can you give us a link to this?